# Android Analytics: Disable Analytics Tracking

Tags: android, google-analytics

Im using Google Analytics in my App and i want the user to be able to enable or disable the analytics tracking. The documentation says:

```
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).setAppOptOut(true);
```

And:

```
You can enable an app-level opt out flag that will disable Google Analytics across the entire app. 
Note that this flag must be set each time the app starts up and will default to false.
```

For me this is confusing because i dont know if i have to set `setAppOptOut` to true or to false if i want to completely disable analytics. So must the boolean value be true or false to completely disable analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable set it to `true`. It is set to `false` by default, meaning it is enabled by default.